# How to use HTTP POST in C++ with Wininet

Tags: c++

I am sending values of two variables using POST to the PHP server. The C++ application using Wininet connects to the server side script, but instead of sending the data correctly, it just shows empty fields in the parameters send using POST.

```
 #include <windows.h> #include <wininet.h> #include <stdio.h> #include <fstream> #include <cstring> 
#pragma comment (lib, "Wininet.lib")
#define SIZE 128

int main() {

HINTERNET Initialize, Connection, File;
DWORD dwBytes;
static const char *postData = "name=Jack+Din&age=38";

LPSTR accept1[2] = { "Accept: */*", NULL };

const char * const frmdata = "name=Arun+Pushkar&age=38";

static const char *hdrs[] = { "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" };

static const char *accept[] = { "*/*", NULL };

char ch;

Initialize = InternetOpen(L"HTTPGET", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

if (!Initialize)
{
    printf("Failed to open session\n");
    exit(0);
}

Connection = InternetConnect(Initialize, L"192.168.1.10", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
    NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

File = HttpOpenRequest(
    Connection,
    L"POST",
    L"/trydata.php",
    L"HTTP/1.0",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 
    0);

unsigned long dataLen = strlen((char*)frmdata)+1;

bool res = HttpSendRequest(
    File,  // file to which reply will come
    (LPCWSTR)hdrs, 
    0,
    (char*)frmdata,   // post variables to be send
    dataLen);          // length of data send

if (res)
{
    std::ofstream webSource;

    webSource.open("a.html");

    while (InternetReadFile(File, &ch, 1, &dwBytes))
    {
        if (dwBytes != 1)break;
        webSource << ch;
    }
    webSource.close();
}

InternetCloseHandle(File);
InternetCloseHandle(Connection);
InternetCloseHandle(Initialize);

return 0;

}
```

The server side script is

```
<?php
$yourname = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : 'no name';
$yourage = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : 'no age';
echo "Hello".htmlspecialchars($yourname). "!";
echo "Your Age".htmlspecialchars($yourage). "!";
?>
```

When I run this C++ code I get the following in my a.html:

```
Hello no Name!Your Age no Age!
```

Comment: You aren't actually referencing `postData` or `frmdata` in your snippet.

Comment: `(LPCWSTR)hdrs`  You can't just cast narrow strings to wide strings and hope for the best.

Comment: @ voidStar i am using frmdata. @retiredNinja But what is the solution

Comment: The solution, when you need a wide string, is to provide a wide string.  `const wchar_t * const frmdata = L"name=Arun+Pushkar&age=38";`  If you have to cast your parameters to make it compile then it's very likely your parameters are the wrong type.

Answer (score -1):

I would use ATL Server classes to do the same. Here is the example:

```
CAtlHttpClient client; 
AtlNavigateData navData; 
LPCSTR lpData = "data=toto"; 
navData.SetMethod(ATL_HTTP_METHOD_POST); 
navData.SetPostData((BYTE*)lpData, lstrlenA(lpData), _T("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")); 
client.Navigate(_T("mysite.net"),      _T("myscript.php"),    &navData);     
const char* pszBody = (const char*)client.GetBody();
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how to use these classes ant tutorial for using

Comment: ATL Server was developed by Microsoft and is fully documented. You can find class references in MSDN